# How do I modify a JSON object?

Tags: postgresql, json, array

I have a table "raw_data" in which I have a field "data" containing a json array like:

```
{'a' : 1, 
'b' : 2,
'c' : 3}
```

I would like two different things:

- Append a new item like `{'d' : 4}` at the end of the array, that would give me :
  `{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 4}`
- Update the key `'c'` with the value `5` in this array, that would give me:    `{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 5}`
- Upsert the already existing key `'d'` with the value `6` in this array, that would give me:    `{'a' : 1, 'b' : 2, 'c' : 3, 'd' : 6}`

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233542/appending-pushing-and-removing-from-a-json-array-in-postgresql-9-5), but couldn't manage to understand how it applies to my specific case

Comment: Have a look: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30707482/3270427

Comment: It's a JSON column. I already found this post, but didn't make it...

Comment: That's not a json array, it's a json object.

Comment: the short answer is you don't  modification is only supported on jsonb, the long answer is, if you don't need the json features than jsonb does not have (eg: duplicate keys) convert to jsonb, modify, and convert back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post you linked to was mine. That was on an array, but the operator is the same for an object (`||`) concatentation.

- Append a new item like `{'d' : 4}`

  ```
  SELECT $${"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}$$::jsonb || '{"d":4}';
  ```
- Update the key `'c'` with the value 5

  ```
  SELECT ($${"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}$$::jsonb || '{"d":4}') || {"c":5}';
  ```
- Upsert the already existing key `'d'` with the value 6

  ```
  SELECT (($${"a":1,"b":2,"c":3}$$::jsonb || '{"d":4}') || '{"c":5}') || '{"d":6}';
  ```

End result,

```
{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 5, "d": 6}
```

Comment: I finally took the time to implement your answer. And I would like to adapt it to do an upster, but I have an error message which is basicly (translated from French...) "Reference to the column "data" is ambiguous". Here is my query : `INSERT INTO raw_data ("data")
VALUES (%s) 
ON CONFLICT ("ID") 
DO
 UPDATE
   SET "data" = "data" || {'d':6}`

Comment: Data is non-reserved. Quoting it shouldn't make a difference. I would not quote data. And I would not quote ID. And I would make all of my columns lowercase (unquoted) @Maxime